# Linq-To-Sql with WCF, Models, and POCO ViewModels Disconnected "DataContext" Timestamp/Rowversion

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, wcf, linq-to-sql

I have a Linq-To-Sql based repository class which I have been successfully using. I am adding some functionality to the solution, which will provide WCF based access to the database.

I have not exposed the generated Linq classes as DataContracts, I've instead created my own "ViewModel" as a POCO for each entity I am going to be returning.

My question is, in order to do updates and take advantage of some of the Linq-To-Sql features like cyclic references from within my Service, do I need to add a Rowversion/Timestamp field to each table in by database so I can use code like `dc.Table.Attach(myDisconnectedObject)`? The alternitive, seems ugly:

```
var updateModel = dc.Table.SingleOrDefault(t => t.ID == myDisconnectedObject.ID);
updateModel.PropertyA = myDisconnectedObject.PropertyA;
updateModel.PropertyB = myDisconnectedObject.PropertyB;
updateModel.PropertyC = myDisconnectedObject.PropertyC;
// and so on and so forth
dc.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: you can also use reflection to set fields if all of them have the same names in linq and your own classes

Comment: How would the performance on something like that be? Could you post an example, because that *sounds* like the best of both worlds to me... I wouldn't need to worry about updating code if I add database fields, just make sure the designer is up to date, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess a RowVersion/TimeStamp column on each table might be the best and least intrusive option - just basically check for that one value, and you're sure whether or not your data might have been modified in the mean time. All other columns can be set to `Update Check=Never`. This will take care of handling the possible concurrency issues when updating your database from "returning" objects.

However, the other thing you should definitely check out is [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com) - it's a great little component to ease those left-right-assignment orgies you have to go through when using ViewModels / Data Transfer Objects by making this mapping between two object types a snap. It's well used, well tested, used by many and very stable - a winner!

Comment: What're your thoughts on the comment to my question about using Reflection to deal with the left-right-assignment code?

Comment: @Nate: that's basically what AutoMapper does - in a nicely wrapped package, so you don't have to deal with too many of the gory details.